# mongoose update not calling back instantly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am sure this is simply a misunderstanding, but I can't figured it out :/

I am trying to update a document in mongoDB, using mongoose on a node server.

My code looks like this:

```
Message.update(searchQuery, updateQuery, function(err, response)
{
    if(err) return handleError(err);
    if(response) console.log(util.inspect(response));
});
```

When I first call this function, the callback is not executed and no changes are applied to the database. Effectively, the update does not happen.

When I call the function a second time, the callback from the first call returns and the changes from the fist update are applied to the DB. The callback for the second call does not return though and no changes for the second call are apllied.

When I call it for the third time, callback 2 returns and changes 2 are applied, but not callback and changes 3. And so on...

I assumed it has something to do with the mongoose function not directly executing when no callback is specified, so I tried adding an empty "options" array:

`Message.update(searchQuery, updateQuery, **{}**, function(err, response){...});`

or executing the update explicitly:

`Message.update(searchQuery, updateQuery).exec( function(err, response){...});`

The results were unchanged though.

Comment: Missing callbacks are usually caused by the update waiting for the connection to be opened. Has your `mongoose.connect` call been made before the first call to `update`?

Comment: That's it! I did not think about that, because it eventually got updated. Can you post your comment as answer and potentially explain why it worked at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing Mongoose callbacks are typically caused by the update waiting for the connection to be opened, as any calls to `update`, `save`, `find`, etc. will be queued up by Mongoose until the `mongoose.connect` call has completed.

So ensure your `mongoose.connect` call is being made before your call to `update`.

Comment: Gawd! I've spent 2 weeks adding test (which keep passing), switching implementations only to scratch my head why my mongoose update went to blackhole.
You are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to call update with mongoose is the following:

```
Message.update(query, update).exec(callback);
```

Whats exactly in your `updateQuery`?

Comment: Complete call: `dbManager.updateMessage({ _id : loggedMessage._id.toString() }, { received : true });` loggedMessage is a mongoose model

Comment: Why do you do a `_id.toString()` here? And what is in your dbManager.updateMessage method?

Comment: _id itself is of type ObjectID: `ObjectID - _bsontype: "ObjectID" - id: "UCëÅxt`+o¸"` and needs to be cast to string to return "55437febc57874602b6fb895" which is the ID of the object in mongo.

Comment: The _id will not be found unless you wrap it in an ObjectId field:

    `{_id:new ObjectId("4f91bfcfaa7c5687a0c686d4")}`

It does not explain why your callback gets resolved on a second/third call to update, though...

Comment: hmmm, somehow it works though. After the second update returns, the received field of the first message is set correctly.